# When is this norm defined ( continuous functions and entire functions)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, entire-functions

Note : This question was asked 7 hours ago but closed so I thought about it again and asking it with my attempts . Hope , it on -site now.

The following question was asked  in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking for help here.

[image]

> 

Both continuity and entire function implies that sup will be attained as set is compact. entire implies further that sup will be attained at the boundary. Also, $||f||_K$ =0 implies that f(z)=0.But By this I marked all options are correct but answer is

> D only

So, Please tell what mistake I am making .
I have done a course on functional analysis and followed Krieszig.

Can you please give outline of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Vert f\Vert_K=0$ does not imply that $f=0$. First, it is possible that $K=\{z_0\}$, a single point. For example, if $K=\{0\}$ and $f(z)=z^2$, then $\sup_{z\in K}|f(z)|=0$, so $\Vert f\Vert_K=0$, but $f\neq 0$. This invalidates options A and B. If $K$ has non-empty interior, then it is still possible that a continuous function $f$ is zero on all of $K$, but nonzero off of $K$. For example, $K=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\leq 1\}$ and $$f(z)=\begin{cases} 0 & |z|\leq 1\\ |z|-1 & |z|>1\end{cases}.$$ This invalidates C. But if an entire function is zero on a nonempty open set (such as the interior of $K$), then it is zero on all of $\mathbb C$. Therefore, $D$ is correct.